# Problem with Solving ODE containing PolyGamma function

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

Please see the attached screenshot of the code which was written in Mathematica 8 on Windows  for solving differential equation contaning PolyGamma function and then plotting it. Now the same code is not working in Mathematica 10. Can someone help me in rectifying it?

[image: PolyGamma ODE]

Answer (score 1):

Since Mathematica is happy to treat PolyGamma as a function in it's own right you really want to be using Solve. While you're right that `PolyGamma` is a differential function of `Gamma`, there are similar relationships between $\cos$ and $\sin$, and we wouldn't whip out a differential equation solver (necessarily) to solve $ \sin(f[x])=\cos(g[x])+\cdots $.  We would solve using inverse functions of $\sin{}$ and $\cos{}$.

This is indeed what `DSolve` was doing even in Mathematica 8, wrapping `Solve`.  The short answer is to just use `Solve` with the `InverseFunctions->True` argument:

```
Tc = 89.9; m = 2.71;
eqn= Log[Tc/x]  == PolyGamma[(x + Tc + y[x])/(2 x)] - PolyGamma[1/2] ;
sol=Solve[eqn, y[x], InverseFunctions -> True] // Flatten
```

Interestingly, with exact `Tc=899/100` your equation has a cute simplification:

```
FullSimplify[eqn]
```

yields

```
HarmonicNumber[(899 - 10 x + 10 y[x])/(20 x)] == Log[899/(40 x)]
```

Whose solution with inverse functions yields:

```
{y[x] -> (-899 + 10*x + 20*x*InverseFunction[HarmonicNumber][Log[899/(40*x)]])/10}
```